Aveva PDMS through python
Is there any solution to create a program with pyhton 3.10 that user can enter pdms login page requiremnt (prject, username, password, MDB) and extract some report from aveva pdms
I want to get report of sctn object start and end point

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Maybe this can help: https://github.com/shivangKheradiya/PyAVEVAE3D

"PyAVEVAE3D contains Proof of Concept for Python 3 embedding into AVEVA Plant Design Products ( e.g. PDMS, E3D2.1/ 3.1, Diagrams, Engineering). These software are based on PML & PML.Net."

